How can I secure routes with react router?
I want to use React Router for my website, but I'm doing something wrong.
The routes that I defined are:
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <SecuredApp>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>}/>
          
          <Route element={<SecuredRoute />}>
            <Route path='/home' element={<Home/>}/>
            <Route path='/perfil' element={<Profile/>}/>
          </Route>
          <Route path='/' element={<Navigate exact from='/' to='/home' />}/>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </SecuredApp>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

At college, I've been taught to use something as SecuredApp and SecuredRoute so, when a user tries to enter at /home (for example) without login, it will redirect him to /login.
I defined those like this:
import {Navigate, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import API from '../../api'

const AuthenticationContext = React.createContext({
    isAuthenticated: false,
    errors: false,
    login: () => {},
    logout: () => {},
    reset: () => {}
})
const client = API.instance()


// eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
function SecuredApp({children}) {

    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authenticated') || false))
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState(false)

    const reset = async () => {
        localStorage.setItem('authenticated', JSON.stringify(false))
        setErrors(false)
        setIsAuthenticated(false)
    }
    const login = async (user, pass) => {
        const loginSuccessful = await client.login(user, pass)
        localStorage.setItem('authenticated', JSON.stringify(loginSuccessful))
        setIsAuthenticated(loginSuccessful)
        setErrors(!loginSuccessful)
    }
    const logout = async () => {
        await client.logout()
        await reset()
    }

    const context = { isAuthenticated, login, logout, errors, reset }

    return <AuthenticationContext.Provider value = { context } >
        { children }
    </AuthenticationContext.Provider>

}

// eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
function SecuredRoute({children, ...props}) {

    const {isAuthenticated} = useContext(AuthenticationContext)
    return isAuthenticated ? <Route {...props}>{children}</Route> : <Navigate to = '/login' />

}

export { AuthenticationContext, SecuredApp, SecuredRoute }

It succeeds to redirect to login when the user hasn't authenticated but, when I log in, I encounter this problem:
    at invariant (react-router-dom.js?v=ef4966f0:209:11)
    at Route (react-router-dom.js?v=ef4966f0:3934:10)
    at renderWithHooks (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:12171:26)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:14921:21)
    at beginWork (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:15902:22)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:3674:22)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:3699:24)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:3733:39)
    at beginWork$1 (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:19761:15)
    at performUnitOfWork (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:19194:20)
react-router-dom.js?v=ef4966f0:209 Uncaught Error: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>.
    at invariant (react-router-dom.js?v=ef4966f0:209:11)
    at Route (react-router-dom.js?v=ef4966f0:3934:10)
    at renderWithHooks (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:12171:26)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:14921:21)
    at beginWork (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:15902:22)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:3674:22)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:3699:24)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:3733:39)
    at beginWork$1 (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:19761:15)
    at performUnitOfWork (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:19194:20)
chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:14036 The above error occurred in the <Route> component:

    at Route (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=ef4966f0:3934:10)
    at SecuredRoute (http://localhost:5173/src/context/auth/index.jsx?t=1715532288323:61:25)
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=ef4966f0:3560:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=ef4966f0:3995:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=ef4966f0:3938:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=ef4966f0:4678:5)
    at SecuredApp (http://localhost:5173/src/context/auth/index.jsx?t=1715532288323:23:23)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:19409 Uncaught Error: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>.
    at invariant (react-router-dom.js?v=ef4966f0:209:11)
    at Route (react-router-dom.js?v=ef4966f0:3934:10)
    at renderWithHooks (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:12171:26)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:14921:21)
    at beginWork (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:15902:22)
    at beginWork$1 (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:19749:22)
    at performUnitOfWork (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:19194:20)
    at workLoopSync (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:19133:13)
    at renderRootSync (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:19112:15)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (chunk-YYQEUSG3.js?v=ef4966f0:18732:28)

Thank you in advance, I hope someone can help me spot my mistake

Did you google your error message? Or how to write such a component?
